# How to reach route parameters in middleware?

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using gorilla mux for request routing.
I wrote a basic middleware which I want to add `user` variable to context for reach in handlers. But I chould not found how can I get route parameter in the middleware:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/{username}/accounts", AccountListHandler)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", AuthMiddleware(router)))
```

Middleware code:

```
func AuthMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // params := mux.Vars(r)
        // fmt.Printf("%v", params["username"])
        user := User{Username: "myUsername"}
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", user)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

I want to reach `username` paramter in the middleware. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it setup you will not be able to access the `username`. The reason for that is that your `AuthMiddleware` is executed **before** the path parameters are extracted by the `router` since it is wrapped inside your middleware (`AuthMiddleware(router)`).

You need use your middleware to wrap your handlers and then register it with the router like so:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/{username}/accounts", AuthMiddleware(AccountListHandler))

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

If you have many handlers that you want to wrap with your middleware without having to repeat yourself too much you can write a simple loop like so:

```
var handlers = map[string]http.HandlerFunc{
    "/{username}/accounts": AccountListHandler,
    // ...
}

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)    
for pattern, handler := range handlers {
    router.HandleFunc(pattern, AuthMiddleware(handler))
}

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```